# depth of recursion and one fact?

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, data-structures, quicksort

I see this text:

[image]

one problem arises:

**but you see in normal quick sort that when we have 1 element in one sub array and n-1 others in next sub array we get depth of O(n) in using stack. this is contrast to this fact? where is the problem?**

Where is the misunderstanding point for me on this topic?

Comment: not the right place to ask this

Comment: Constant fraction is something like `1/10`. If you only put 1 out of `n` elements in a subarray, that's `1/n`, a non-constant fraction. A constant fraction will move (for large enough `n`) a linear number of elements into one partition or the other.

Comment: In normal quick sort you get depth n when the worst case for pivot is chosen each time not just once. The worst case occurs for instance when: 1) data is already sorted in forward or reverse order, 2) all elements are the same, 3) max value is chosen as pivot each time.

Comment: @DarrylG.   this sentence start with if. but we know in randomized quick sort depth of stack never occurred more that O(log n). so why start this with if? maybe randomized produce a case in which one side not be a constant fraction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are misinterpreting the meaning of "constant fraction". It does not mean you place a constant *number* of elements in one partition, and the remaining in another. If you put `k` elements in one partition, the *fraction* is `k/n`, which is *not* constant.

On the other hand, if you always put `1/k` elements (for some constant `k`) in one partition, for large enough `n` that's a *linear* number of elements. For `k = 100000`, that's still `n/100000` elements on one side and `99999/100000 n` elements on the other.

Comment: We *don't* know that. Randomized quicksort could pick the minimum or maximum value as the pivot, which could (depending on which half the pivot is assigned to) result in no branching at all.

Answer (score 0):

The important part is "constant **fraction** of the elements". If you hit a degenerate Quicksort case where the partitioning puts a constant **number** (e.g. 1) of elements on one side of the partition, you'll get O(n^2) time complexity.

But if every partitioning call puts a constant **fraction** (e.g. 99%) of elements on one side, you'll still get O(n log n) (albeit with a larger constant factor).